# How do I get the ec2 tag Name from my ec2 hosts?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm wanting to extract the "Name" tag from ec2 instances.  How do I do that?  It doesn't seem to be part of ec2_facts

Answer (score 0):

Ansible recommends using [dynamic inventories](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) to manage AWS EC2 instances.

The docs explain the basic setup, afterwards you can address an EC2 instance like any other host via tags. Say, your instance is called  `web`, you can address it later in a playbook via

```
hosts: tag_Name_web
```